# SUM of multiple columns using SELF JOIN in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table - table1 like below:

```
+------+--------+--------+-----+

ID---hours1---hours2-----hours3--+

1-------4-------3---------2----+

2-------8-------7---------6----+

1-------5-------2---------1----+

2-------10------11--------2----+
```

Expected Results:

```
ID-----Total

1--------17

2--------44
```

I tried SELF join query as below:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(hours1 + hours2 + hours3) 
from table1 a inner join table1 b ON a.Id = b.Id 
group by a.Id
```

However this is giving incorrect results and results are very weird. Can anyone please help me what's wrong in above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the self-join is required for this, just:

```
select t.id, sum(t.hours1+t.hours2+t.hours3) as total
from table1 t
group by t.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks like i was overthinking on this one!